# The differential: from approximation to equality

Tags: differential

I was reading Leithold and the introduction to differentials deals with approximations, $\Delta y \approx f’(x) \Delta x$. This approximation is usable for small values of $\Delta x$.

Then the definition is made using a equality: $dy = f’(x)dx$.

Please explain this jump from $\approx$ to $=$

Comment: One is $\Delta y$ and the other is $dy$.  There's no conflict.

Comment: $dx$ is used when you consider the limit of $\Delta x \to 0$. In this process, the error appearing in the approximation, vanishes. Thus, with no error (the error is zero),, approximation is actually an equality-

Answer (score 0):

What do you even mean by $dy=f'(x)dx$? Can you explain what is the definition of $dx,dy$ and $f'(x)$?